# Orchard - How to create a new product page?

Tags: orchardcms

I have to create this "Add New Product" page. The page will have four radio buttons at the top, for different product types. Depending on which product/radio button was selected, I have to display different input fields. About 50% of the fields are common to all 4 product types, rest are different for each product type. And I want to (have to) save the data in the same database table (there will be few empty columns in each row).

Any suggestion on how to I implement this page? (one content type, multiple content types, content parts, widgets...?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided thus far, one approach is to write client-side logic (in Javascript) to add the buttons to the appropriate place in your page and modify the layout of your page based upon which button is pressed. For this, you don't need to modify anything within Orchard.

You could create a new "layer" in Orchard that applies only to pages under a particular path and a widget that injects your javascript into this layer. This also requires no modification to Orchard itself.

Does this work for you?